# Hadoop 2.7.2 single node installation ubuntu src-code does not has /etc/hadoop dir

Tags: java, ubuntu, hadoop-2.7.2

i am setting up hadoop-2.7.2 on ubuntu 14.10 . the source code which downloaded from https://hadoop.apache.org does not have /etc directory .
so where i have to configure JAVA_HOME variable ?
it should be in hadoop-2.7.2/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get set up with a Hadoop sandbox I've ever seen is the [HortonWorks Data Platform sandbox VM](http://hortonworks.com/downloads/). Use that to get up to speed instead of rolling your own. It comes with Hadoop, HBase, Spark and a bunch of other stuff ready to go with minimal fuss and is designed to be used to support development on your workstation from the guest OS.